# How can I lock auto rotate on the website for the mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, screen-rotation

I use this way:

```
   @media (max-height: 480px) and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 600px) { 
    html{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
           -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
           -moz-transform-origin: left top;
            -ms-transform-origin: left top;
             -o-transform-origin: left top;
                transform-origin: left top;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
            left: 0
    }
```

but when I rotate my phone, I see white display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use media query with orientation for this:

`@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}`

The trick here is to detect the changed orientation and using CSS transform to rotate the content of your web page so as to mock orientation-lock.

If you are comfortable with the idea of using Javascript to accomplish this then you can try this:

```
screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
```

See:

- https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/
- https://caniuse.com/screen-orientation

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I see white display too, when I rotate my device.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @ЮрийБуцан it might have something to do with the css of your webpage. You can try finding the root cause or can try the js method which I have suggested in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/ and use:

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait')
screen.orientation.lock('landscape')
screen.orientation.unlock()
```